# Throws System Access Violation in compiled form but not in VS2010 Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

The following code throws a system access violation exception ONLY when called from the command prompt. Why? When run the exception is thrown on line 148 of fstream. This does NOT occur when debugging in VS, but only when I try to run the compiled program from the command  prompt, same for an elevated command prompt.

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

ifstream::pos_type size;
int filesize;
char * memblock;

int main() { 
    fstream wfile ( "C:\\Plans\\Plan.txt" , ios::out|ios::ate|ios::app);
    if(wfile.is_open())                                               
    {
        wfile<<"\n";
        wfile.close();
    }

    ifstream file ( "C:\\Plans\\Plan.txt" , ios::in|ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open()){
        int size = file.tellg();
        filesize= size;
        memblock = new char [size];
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read (memblock, size);
        file.close();                                       

        cout << size << " bytes loaded into memory" << endl;
        return 1;                                                                             
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;         
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line does the exception occur on?  What is the exact text of the exception?

Comment: 2 bytes loaded into memory.   Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write from protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at std.basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >/{dtor}(basic_streambuf<char\,std::char_traits<char> >* )

Comment: The file it is opening is about 5k in size

Comment: OK, I don't agree with the downvote, but you *are* giving us cryptic information. Slow down, backup, edit your question, and give us *all* the details. (For example, telling us the exception occurs on line 148 doesn't help, given your un-numbered code snippet.)

Comment: The error it is giving me on line 148 of fstream IS the exception.  The exception does not occur when debugging in VS2010, only when the program is run from the command prompt.

Comment: If I take a screenshot of the output would that help?

Comment: I am not trying to be cryptic, this is baffling me as well.

Comment: Add the details to your question. Edit it. Don't put them in the comments.

Comment: I realize you are fairly new here, so let me clarify what I'm asking for: It would be helpful if you would post a complete & *buildable* code segment. When I place your code in a new C++ project, it doesn't build. Try it. So boil your code down to only what is necessary to reproduce the bug (this process may actually help to clarify the problem in your own mind, and lead you to your own solution; it often does for me).

Comment: Does [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013682/clr-console-program-runs-fine-inside-vs2010-but-from-the-command-prompt-it-is-u) still refer to the same issue as this question?

Comment: Line 148?  The code you posted doesn't have line numbers.

Comment: 148 of fstream you know the ANSI-C standard libray.  And that code is now build able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't creating a large enough buffer, because you're not using `ios::binary`. Each `'\n'` in the file will be expanded to `'\r\n'`; since you sized the buffer to the number of bytes in the file, it can't handle the expansion and you're getting a classic buffer overrun.

Comment: Yup this is what is happening.

Comment: Peppered the program with _ASSERT( _CrtCheckMemory( ) ); statements to localize the buffer overrun.  As it turns out the issue was caused right before before this section of code was executed, but manifested it self in the release DLL's but not with the debug dll's.   The exact cause of the overrun was a strcpy_s copying the value from argv to the myFile pointer.  Which was not in the code sample provided.  I was forced to change my method of assigning myFile, any version of strcpy_s run with argv corrupted the heap.